# is there any way to extract the link from the bitmap image with 100% accuracy using google vision ml kit, android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, ocr, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I have this image, I am trying to extract the link from the image using google ml Kit but getting the wrong hyperlink, as you know that if it is a wrong hyperlink, it's of no use. After[image] processing the image, it is giving the result and the hyperlink is wrong.
httos://ww.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov2RNI3DBYE                                                                   httos://ww.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov2RNI3DBYE